# Where are the missing commas in the text below?

Tags: commas

For works of art and the finest treasures of the Renaissance period look no further than the beautiful city of Florence. This is the home of the famous Michelangelo statue of David amazing paintings by da Vinci and Botticelli in the Uffizi Gallery and the magnificent Duomo. Enjoy an evening stroll on the medieval Ponte Vecchio a photographer’s paradise or climb Giotto’s bell tower for a wonderful panoramic view of Florence.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a homework question - are you having any specific problems with the commas? Unsure about certain placements?

Comment: This is an english exam which I got stuck for a long time to find the right answer for that.

Comment: Did you do any research? If so, please share that with us. If it was for an exam you already took, what did you put? Maybe we can help you understand why your answer was wrong.

Comment: I really want to know where would I put the commas in this text exactly.

Comment: I put after Period, David and Vecchio. don't you have any idea?

Comment: I do, but this isn't a homework help site. These question are intended to help you (and others who may have the same question) learn. Proofreading isn't on-topic unless a specific source of concern is identified - for instance, if you asked something like "why does this comma belong here?", that's more on-topic.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but my problem is that I have published  my answer to this question on internet which was as follow,

Comment: For works of art and the finest treasures of the Renaissance period look no further than the
beautiful city of Florence. This is the home of the
famous Michelangelo statue of David, amazing paintings by da Vinci and Botticelli in the
Uffizi Gallery and the magnificent Duomo.
Enjoy a romantic evening stroll on the mediaeval Ponte Vecchio, a photographer’s
paradise. Climb Giotto’s bell tower for a wonderful panoramic view of Florence.

Comment: everybody says that this is correct but I don't know why the exam is failing me.

Comment: Okay - thanks for posting what you tried for an answer. That helps. I'll post an answer and try to explain reasoning as I go along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For works of art and the finest treasures of the Renaissance **period, look** no further than the beautiful city of Florence.

The first part of this sentence ("For works of art and the finest treasures of the Renaissance period") is a [dependent clause](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/dependclterm.htm) that starts the sentence, so it needs to have a comma to separate it.

> This is the home of the famous Michelangelo statue of David, amazing paintings by da Vinci and Botticelli in the Uffizi **Gallery, and** the magnificent Duomo.

This comma is debatable. It's referred to as the ["oxford" or "serial" comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/2015/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/) and is slowly going out of style. Since there are three things in this list (1 - statue of David, 2 - paintings, and 3 - Duomo), you should probably put a comma here. Personally, because you're taking an English exam, I would include it.

> Enjoy a romantic evening stroll on the mediaeval Ponte Vecchio, a photographer’s **paradise, or** climb Giotto’s bell tower for a wonderful panoramic view of Florence.

"A photographer's paradise" is a phrase that can't stand on its own, so it needs it's own set of commas (one before and one after) to put it off from the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,That really helped. Does it make sense if we separate `This is the home of the famous Michelangelo' by a comma from `statue of David'?

Comment: I don't think so. I know just a smidge about art, and the actual statue is "David" not "Michelangelo". Michelangelo was the artist.

Comment: It's not the home of Michelangelo (well, I guess it might be, but that's not what the sentence is trying to convey), it's the home of the Michelangelo statue, so there shouldn't be a comma.